# How to I place my logo next to the input field?

Tags: css

I am having a problem with my [website](http://www.onetechsearch.com/tech/category/all/?search=&to=&cat=all), the problem is the fact that the logo is displayed at the top of the page. How can I display it next to the #sfield?

Comment: any codes we can work with?

Comment: Adding a `float` left or right css property to the `#topbar h1` element can also achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You want the "OTS" logo on the left of the search field or something like that right?

The easiest way to accomplish this is to set the logo's position to absolute which allows it be literally in any position you set it to, if you're still having trouble then try setting the search box's div to absolute.

Adjust other properties like left, top, etc... accordingly afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, what is that page.

Heres how you do it:

```
#topbar h1 {
    background: url(http://www.onetechsearch.com/wp-content/themes/mamatoti/images/logo.png) no-repeat center center;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 195px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1px;
```

add position and right

Comment: This adds the logo to the right, and if I change `left: 1px;` it just displays over the searchfield